# Cannot wake up from hibernate 14.04

Tags: suspend, bug-reporting

I've brought a new laptop(Lenovo Thinkpad Edge e440). My laptop doesn't want to wake up from hibernation (i'm pressing any key or power button, but there's no reaction from PC) . Where's problem ?

Here is : 
**pm-suspend.log**
http://pastebin.com/wbrDf2dW

**Intel HD Graphics 4600**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=187624

You have to disable USB 3.0 in BIOS